# how to configure the azure app to send a notification when a user is deleted from the app

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory

Everyone is fine? I have an azure AD registered app that integrates into a php system using a single login with the SAML protocol.

everything works fine, but I need to set up a request so that when the user is deleted by the administrator it sends a request to my server so I can log the user out and remove it from my system.

**what have I tried?**

- I tried to use provisioning but I didn't get the result I wanted, even setting the correct mapping.
- I've wondered how I can do this with provisioning, trying to understand how to send when the user is deleted in azure to my system, but I don't understand how I can do this.

**what do i really want?**

When the app's adm deletes the user, it sends a request for a route configured on my server so that I can also delete the user from my server.

Comment: Please check  Deprovising part of this  MS document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/how-provisioning-works

Comment: Hello @Lorenzo Correa, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We will be able to get alerts by  [Use the Microsoft Graph API to get change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) for changes in user data, whether deleted ,added or any changes .

Also Based on the [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/how-provisioning-works#de-provisioning)

> A user is soft deleted in Azure AD (sent to the recycle bin /
> AccountEnabled property set to false). 30 days after a user is deleted
> in Azure AD, they will be permanently deleted from the tenant. At this
> point, the provisioning service will send a DELETE request to
> permanently delete the user in the application. At any time during the
> 30-day window, you can [manually delete a user
> permanently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-restore),
> which sends a delete request to the application.

For more information please refer the below links:

- MS Q&A:  [Get notifications based on new user added or deleted in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/597295/get-notifications-based-on-new-user-added-or-delet.html)
- MSFT| PowerAutomate: [Connector: Azure AD, Trigger, New](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Connector-Azure-AD-Trigger-New/idc-p/106226#M5010)